# strtotime() breaking in new php version when converting mysql timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I'm converting my mysql timestamp with

`$timeStampDate=date("F j, Y g:i a", strtotime($row["projectTimeStamp"]));`

Unfortunately a new php version doesn't like this, and is giving me a set of errors.

```
Strict Standards: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.
```

I've been playing with .htaccess, adding `php_value date.timezone Europe/London` but it's a problem.

I just need the mysql NOW() to be readable in a $variable.

I hate software updates. `PHP Version 5.2.17`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set default timezone with `date_default_timezone_set()`

Comment: This is correct, I just fixed it with date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

Comment: Sorry, I tried to accept it but I needed to wait a designated time. @Tom No need to be rude is there?

Answer (score 1):

Or in php.ini: [datetime.timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php)